# Can AWS lambda deployed as a container in .net 3.1 be debugged locally?

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, containers

To Devs,
My AWS lambda is being deployed as a container in .net 3.1.
I can run the lambda locally in a container using SAM.
How can I attach and setup my Visual Studio 2019 to debug the code?
I am not sure if this is possible.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It can run locally in a Docker container but it can't be debugged via Visual Studio.